# Different binning for histplot as JoinGrid (x,y) marginal plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

|  | Date | Weight | Year | Month | Day | Week | DayOfWeek |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2017-11-13 | 76.1 | 2017 | 11 | 13 | 46 | 0 |
| 1 | 2017-11-14 | 76.2 | 2017 | 11 | 14 | 46 | 1 |
| 2 | 2017-11-15 | 76.6 | 2017 | 11 | 15 | 46 | 2 |
| 3 | 2017-11-16 | 77.1 | 2017 | 11 | 16 | 46 | 3 |
| 4 | 2017-11-17 | 76.7 | 2017 | 11 | 17 | 46 | 4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I created a JoinGrid with:

```
g = sns.JointGrid(data=df,
    x="Date",
    y="Weight",
    marginal_ticks=True,
    height=6, 
    ratio=2, 
    space=.05)
```

Then a defined joint and marginal plots:

```
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot,
        hue=df["Year"], 
        alpha=.4,
        legend=True)
g.plot_marginals(sns.histplot, 
    multiple="stack", 
    bins=20,
    hue=df["Year"])
```

Result is this.

[image: result]

Now the question is: "is it possible to specify different binning for the two histplot resulting in the x and y marginal plot?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do that, by you can plot directly on the marginal axes using the plotting function of your choice, like so:

```
penguins = sns.load_dataset('penguins')

data = penguins
x_col = "bill_length_mm"
y_col = "bill_depth_mm"
hue_col = "species"

g = sns.JointGrid(data=data, x=x_col, y=y_col, hue=hue_col)
g.plot_joint(sns.scatterplot)

# top marginal
sns.histplot(data=data, x=x_col, hue=hue_col, bins=5, ax=g.ax_marg_x, legend=False, multiple='stack')
# right marginal
sns.histplot(data=data, y=y_col, hue=hue_col, bins=40, ax=g.ax_marg_y, legend=False, multiple='stack')
```

[image]